# Remove blank lines at the end of MS CSV files

Tags: shell, unix

I have around 300 csv files places at a path.
These files names have 3 different categories i.e. "*_PROD.csv", "*_DEV.csv" and *_UAT.csv"

These files have many blank lines(around 1000) which got inserted at the end of the records when they were copied to the path by a process.

I want to remove the blank lines from all theses files. I have to perform a merge on these files after the blank spaces are removed.

I have tried the below:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv
sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_DEV.csv
sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_UAT.csv

sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' \
    "${File_Path}"*_{PROD,DEV,UAT}.csv
```

But it's not working.

```
-sh-4.2$  echo sed -i '/^$/d'  Sample_data.csv
sed -i /^$/d Sample_data.csv
```

Sample data:

```
ID,Name ,DB
100,Amit,TD
200,Sumit,Oracle
300,Anshu,MS SQL
,,
,,
500,Jaya,MONGO
600,Sameer,HADOOP
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: sed -i '/^$/d' is correct. Please show me results of: echo sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv

Comment: (Added to the description) echo is just giving that command

Comment: Also added the sample data and one more thing it's a csv file (MS CSV file)

Comment: My file has 14 columns so for all the blank row it will be ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use '/^,*$/d' instead of '/^$/d'.

```
sed '/^,*$/d' ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv > ${File_Path}*_PROD_new.csv
```

Comment: This is not working. Added the output in the description

Comment: Please show me an expected output against Sample data.

Comment: Expected output will be without the blank lines i.e  the , , lines should be removed in my csv file

Comment: Since i copied the files from windows i had to use dos2unix before running the sed command and then it ran fine.  Thanks